# WPF DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate not called for a ContentControl-derived type

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I'm trying to build a `ContentControl`-derived control (let's call it `MyContentControl`) that will have its `ControlTemplate` set by an instance of a `DataTemplateSelector`-derived type (let's call it `MyTemplateSelector`).

When I try to this:

```
ContentControl contentControl = new ContentControl();
contentControl.ContentTemplateSelector = new MyTemplateSelector();
contentControl.Content = "Some ContentControl Content";

MyContentControl myContentControl = new MyContentControl();    
myContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector = new MyTemplateSelector();
myContentControl.Content = "Some MyControl Content";
```

I expect that, when I set content on those controls, `MyTemplateSelector`'s override of `DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate()` method gets called for both `contentControl` and  `myContentControl`.

In reality, it gets called only for contentControl. What do I need to do (and why!) to make it work for `myContentControl` too?

(Not sure if it's relevant, but for the moment `MyContentControl` does not do anything with `DependencyProperties` other than overriding metadata information for `DefaultStyleKeyProperty`.

**EDIT** (moved content from other post to original question):

Here is a bit more elaborated example:

1. Create MyContentControl:

   ```
   public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
   {
     static MyContentControl()
     {
       DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (MyContentControl),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (MyContentControl)));
     }
     public MyContentControl() {}
   }
   ```
2. Create `MyTemplateSelector`:

   ```
   public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
     public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
     {
       return null;  // <== Place the breakpoint here
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add `ContentControl` and `MyContent` control to your main window (for example):

   ```
   <StackPanel>
       <local:MyContentControl x:Name="myContentControl" />
       <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" />
   </StackPanel>
   ```
4. Add this code somewhere after `InitializeComponent` (or in `Loaded` handler):

   ```
   myContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector = new MyTemplateSelector();
   myContentControl.Content = "123";

   contentControl.ContentTemplateSelector = new MyTemplateSelector();
   contentControl.Content = "ABC";
   ```

The breakpoint mentioned in step (2) gets hit only once, for `content="ABC"` and `contentControl` element.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem before, and I solve it with this ([Notify DataTemplateSelector about the change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314560/notify-datatemplateselector-about-the-change)) hint.

My problem was, I want a ContentPresenter which changes embedded UserControl when the ComboBox selection changed.

The Combobox+ContentPresenter XAML is

```
        <ComboBox Name="comboBoxControl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ChangeControlCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=comboBoxControlType}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ComboBoxItem>UserControl-1-</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>UserControl-2-</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
<ContentPresenter Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Source={StaticResource controlCueTemplateSelector}}" 
                      Content="{Binding}" />
```

As you can see, the command binding with MVVM manner was my approach. Although you might not want to write a code-behind, kindly write a code-behind with appropriate event as below.

```
    private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var content = contentPresenter.Content;
        contentPresenter.ClearValue(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty);
        contentPresenter.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, content);
    }
```

Bottomline is, you need to reset the binded target object (in my case, the Content property).

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and the reason that the DataTemplateSelector has been applied for a ContentControl but not for my derived Control was hidden in the ControlTemplate for my derived Control. I simply forgot to add the template binding for the ContentTemplateSelector:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UniControl}">
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"/>
</Border>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That saved me some coins.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to post more of your code, because I just created a simple example and it worked fine. My `DataTemplate` only contains a `TextBox`, my `DataTemplateSelector` always returns that `DataTemplate`, and both a `ContentControl` and a class derived from `ContentControl` use my `DataTemplateSelector`. In both cases a `TextBox` was displayed.